# exploding map div on tap on ipad

Tags: ios, leaflet

I'm developping a leaflet app for mobile devices. It seemed to be working OK till today on the Ipad. On an android all works as planned. On an Ipad the map stays in the div I set for it I can use the links in the navbar, zoom by pinching, and move the map around. But when i tap on the map or a marker. Then the map fills the whole screen and links become inoperable.
I managed to place a button over the map, but on tapping the map makes it dissappear off the screen. Not under the map but dissappeared.
On a mac safari I had the same problem, but adding z-index:10000 to the navbar keeps the map under the navbar.
this is the link

https://www.normandy-tour-guide.com/itin/bob1234/map.php

any suggestions would be most welcome

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Band of Brothers</title>
    
        <!--leaflet css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css"
            integrity="sha256-kLaT2GOSpHechhsozzB+flnD+zUyjE2LlfWPgU04xyI=" crossorigin="" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/leaflet-routing-machine.css" />
    
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/map.css">
        <script>
        let page = document.cookie;
        console.log(page);
        let cName = "page";
        console.log(cName);
    
    
        function getCookie(cName) {
            const name = cName + "=";
            const cDecoded = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie); //to be careful
            const cArr = cDecoded.split('; ');
            let res;
            cArr.forEach(val => {
                if (val.indexOf(name) === 0) res = val.substring(name.length);
            })
            console.log(cName);
            console.log(res);
            return res
        }
        getCookie("page");
        </script>
        <?php
    
    $page = $_COOKIE["page"];
    ?>
        <script>
        page = <?php echo $page; ?>;
        console.log("which pâge" + page);
        </script>
    
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="title navmap ">
            <h1>Band of Brothers Itinerary</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar navmap ">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="stands.php">STANDS</a></li>
                <li><a href="poi.php">POIs</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    
        <div id="map">(
            <?php
        //echo " Cookie" . $_COOKIE["n_data"];
        $N_DATA = $_COOKIE["n_data"];
        //echo "data ".$N_DATA;
    
        if (isset($_GET['choice'])){
        $choice = $_GET['choice'];
        //echo $choice;
    }else{
        $choice = "'a'";
        //echo $choice;
    }
      ?>
             <script>
            let choice = "a";
            choice = <?php echo $choice;?>;
            //alert(choice);
            console.log('CHOICE' + choice);
            </script> 
            <button id="refreshButton">
            Button
          </button>
        </div>
    
        <!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js"
            integrity="sha256-WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM=" crossorigin=""></script>
    
        <script src="../js/leaflet-routing-machine.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/Control.Geocoder.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/config.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/bob-carentan.js"></script>
    
        <!-- geojson data-->
        <script src="../js/data.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../js/bob-resto.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../js/bob-carentan.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../js/map.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
    
        </script>
    
        <script>
        //console.log("Test")
        </script>
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

and this is map.js

```
//var choice = "route";
//console.log(choice);

var map = L.map('map').setView([49.360241, -1.275101], 12);
/*L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',*/ 
L.tileLayer('../tiles/bob1/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
{
maxZoom: 15,
minZoom: 11,
attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'

}).addTo(map);





/* add links to popup */

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    let popupContent = ` ${feature.properties.Stand} </br>`; 
    if(feature.properties.standType=="Stand") {    // && feature.properties.popupContent) {
        // popupContent += feature.properties.popupContent ;
        popupContent += '<a href=\"'+feature.properties.Nu+'\.php\"> Click for Info </a> ';   
    }
    if(feature.properties.telephone) {
        // popupContent = feature.properties.Stand + '</br>';
        popupContent += feature.properties.telephone;
    }
    layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
    //console.log(feature.properties.Nu   )
    //console.log( stands.features.length   )
}

// function onEachFeatureResto(feature, layer) {
//     let popupContent = ` ${feature.properties.Stand} </br>`; 
//     if (feature.properties){    // && feature.properties.popupContent) {
//         // popupContent += feature.properties.popupContent ;
//         popupContent += feature.properties.telephone;   
//     }
//     layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
//     //console.log(feature.properties.Nu   )
//     //console.log( stands.features.length   )
// }



/* Add round markers and tooltips */

const standLayer = L.geoJSON(stands, {

    style(feature) {
        return feature.properties && feature.properties.style;
    },

    onEachFeature,

    pointToLayer(feature, latlng) {
        label = String(feature.properties.Nu) // Must convert to string, .bindTooltip can't use straight 'feature.properties.attribute'
 
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            radius: 15,
            fillColor: '#079',
            color: '#000',
            zindex: 100,
            weight: 1,
            opacity: 1,
            fillOpacity: 0.8
        }).bindTooltip(label, {permanent: true, offset: [10, 0] }).openTooltip();
    }
}).addTo(map);

if (choice=='rest'){
const restLayer = L.geoJSON(resto, {

    style(feature) {
        return feature.properties && feature.properties.style;
    },

    onEachFeature,

    pointToLayer(feature, latlng) {
        label = (feature.properties.Stand) // 'feature.properties.attribute'
 
       
            var smallIcon = new L.Icon({
                iconSize: [20, 20],
                iconAnchor: [13, 27],
                popupAnchor: [1, -24],
                iconUrl: '../images/icons/resto.png'
            });
            return L.marker(latlng, {icon: smallIcon});
        
    
        }
}).addTo(map); 

}

if (choice=='wc'){
    const restLayer = L.geoJSON(wc, {
    
        style(feature) {
            return feature.properties && feature.properties.style;
        },
    
        onEachFeature,
    
        pointToLayer(feature, latlng) {
            label = (feature.properties.Stand) // 'feature.properties.attribute'
     
           
                var smallIcon = new L.Icon({
                    iconSize: [30, 30],
                    iconAnchor: [13, 27],
                    popupAnchor: [1, -24],
                    iconUrl: '../images/icons/wc.png'
                });
                return L.marker(latlng, {icon: smallIcon});
            
        
            }
    }).addTo(map); 
    
    }
    

    if (choice=='atm'){
        const restLayer = L.geoJSON(atm, {
        
            style(feature) {
                return feature.properties && feature.properties.style;
            },
        
            onEachFeature,
        
            pointToLayer(feature, latlng) {
                label = (feature.properties.Stand) // 'feature.properties.attribute'
         
               
                    var smallIcon = new L.Icon({
                        iconSize: [30, 30],
                        iconAnchor: [13, 27],
                        popupAnchor: [1, -24],
                        iconUrl: '../images/icons/atm.png'
                    });
                    return L.marker(latlng, {icon: smallIcon});
                
            
                }
        }).addTo(map); 
        
        }

        if (choice=='mus'){
            const restLayer = L.geoJSON(mus, {
            
                style(feature) {
                    return feature.properties && feature.properties.style;
                },
            
                onEachFeature,
            
                pointToLayer(feature, latlng) {
                    label = (feature.properties.Stand) // 'feature.properties.attribute'
             
                   
                        var smallIcon = new L.Icon({
                            iconSize: [30, 30],
                            iconAnchor: [13, 27],
                            popupAnchor: [1, -24],
                            iconUrl: '../images/icons/mus.png'
                        });
                        return L.marker(latlng, {icon: smallIcon});
                    
                
                    }
            }).addTo(map); 
            
            }
    


const bobcarLayer = L.geoJSON(bobcar);
bobcarLayer.addTo(map);



if (choice=="route"){
    // sending page
    let p = getCookie("page");
    // jump interval
   let p2 = parseInt(p);
    if (p==7||p==5||p==12||p==23){  p2=parseInt(p)+1}
    
    console.log("PAGE="+page)
    var control = L.Routing.control(L.extend(window.lrmConfig, {
        // waypoints: [
        //  L.latLng(49.3489, -1.25254),    
        //  L.latLng(49.32831, -1.26857)   
        // ],
       
       
        waypoints: [
            L.latLng(stands.features[p -1 ].geometry.coordinates[1], 
                stands.features[ p-1 ].geometry.coordinates[0]),    
                L.latLng(stands.features[ p2 ].geometry.coordinates[1], 
                    stands.features[ p2 ].geometry.coordinates[0])   
        ],
        



        geocoder: L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim(),
        routeWhileDragging: false,
        reverseWaypoints: false,
        showAlternatives: false,
        altLineOptions: {
            styles: [
                {color: 'black', opacity: 0.15, weight: 9},
                {color: 'white', opacity: 0.8, weight: 6},
                {color: 'blue', opacity: 0.5, weight: 2}
            ]
        }
    })).addTo(map);
}



//L.control.locate().addTo(map);
```

```
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  /* 1 */
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  /* 2 */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  /* 2 */

  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  max-height: 1000000px;
}

/**
   * Remove default margin.
   */

:root {
  --clr-primary: hsl(236, 76%, 38%);
  --clr-medium: hsl(236, 57%, 80%);
  --clr-light: hsl(56, 31%, 93%);
  --clr-dark: hsl(236, 10%, 0%);
  --clr-accent: hsl(56, 76%, 38%);

  --fw-n: 400;
  --fw-m: 500;
  --fw-b: 700;

  --fs-1: 3rem;
  --fs-2: 2rem;
  --fs-3: 1.4rem;
  --fs-p: 1.1rem;

}

body {
  margin: 0;
  color: var(--clr-dark);
  background: var(--clr-light);

  font: 18px/1.2 "Arial", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  line-height: 2rem;
  min-width: 320px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

a {
  color: var(--clr-accent);
  text-decoration: none;
}

p{
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  text-indent: 5ch;
  font-size: var(--fs-3);
}

.clear{
  clear: both;
}

h1 {
  /*font-size: var(--fs-1);*/
  font-size:calc(100% + 3vw);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1em;
}

h2{
  font-size: var(--fs-3);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1em;
  margin: 0.5em 0;
}

.imgr{
  width:70%;
  float: right;
  margin: 1em ;
}

.imgl{
  width:70%;
  float: left;
  margin: 1em ;
}

.imgnf{
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
}
.imgg{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
}

@media (max-width:600px ){
  .imgr, .imgl , .imgnf{
    width:95%;
  }

}

.button {
  background-color: var(--clr-primary);
  border: none;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.div-button{
  display: flex;
  margin:auto;
}


.buttonl{
  left: 30%;
}


#map {
  margin-top: 3em;
  padding: 0;
  height: 93vh;
  background-color: var(--clr-dark);
}

.content-splash {
  background-image: url(../images/webp/ste-marie-church.webp);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: var(--clr-medium);
  background-size: cover;
height: 100vh;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}

/*

.content-splash ul {
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;

}*/

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

}
.wrapper ul {
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  align-items: center;
 /* margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* For IE, the outcast */
  /*zoom:1;
  display: inline; */
  text-align: center;
 /* display: flex;*/
}
.wrapper li {
  
  float: left;
  clear:both;
  width:25ch;
  padding: 1.8vh;
  margin: 1.5vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  list-style-type: none;

  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, var(--clr-accent), var(--clr-dark));
}

.wrapper li a {
text-align: center;
color: var(--clr-light);
}


.content {
 width: 60ch ;
 max-width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: var(--clr-light);
}

.content ul {
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
}


.content div{
  height: auto;
}
.content-stands a{
  color:var(--clr-primary);
  width: 6em;
}

.content-stands{
  text-transform: uppercase
}
.content-stands ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}
.title {
  height:3em;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-inline: auto;
  background-color: var(--clr-dark);
  color: var(--clr-accent);
}

.navbar {
  position: sticky;
  top:0;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  width: 100%;
  /*display:inline-flex;*/
  background-color: var(--clr-dark);
}

.navbar ul {
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  margin:auto;
}

.navbar ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin-inline: auto;

}

#refreshButton {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 10000;
}

/* .titlemap{
  z-index: 10000;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;

} */

.navmap {
  z-index: 10000;
  
}

.leaflet-control-zoom{
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I "resolved" the problem, although I'm not sure why it exists.
The z-index of 10000 on the nav bar , kept it above the map when it explodes out of it's div. The problem with the Ipad persisted because although I emptied the safari cache , it seems to use old files for some time.
Android works fine.